# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable while calling from function

Tags: python, function, bioinformatics

Dear all I have small question about simple scrip for testing of the occurrence of the motif in DNA sequence.

Firstly without any functions its works perfect but when I moved If statement of the code under function I obtained error after calling this function

```
def Motif(Motif, Seq):


    if Motif in Seq:
        print "!!!wwWOOHOOOoo!!!" +('\n')+ "%s has been detected!!!"%(Motif)+('\n')+"wWOOOHOOOoo!!"



# Script here
Seq = raw_input('Please paste the DNA sequence here:')
Motif = raw_input('Please type the DNA motif here:')

Motif(Motif, Seq)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "simple.py", line 13, in 
    Motif(Motif, Seq)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

What should I to fix in this code ?

Comment: That's because your function has the same name `Motif`.

Answer (score 3):

You rebound `Motif` to a string:

```
Motif = raw_input('Please type the DNA motif here:')
```

This masks the `Motif` function; use a different name instead.

Python functions are objects in the same namespace; `Motif` either refers to the function or the `raw_input()` return value, not both.